# Copy Paste in the wrong cell range between two different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Ive managed and to copy paste data from one workbook to master workbook, HOWEVER, the data is not pasted into the right place. The data is copied within the range ("A1:C12") of the source workbook, but its is pasted in range "M75:O86") in the Master workbook. I will like it to be pasted in Range ("A1:C12") within the master workbook. Please help.

```
   Option Explicit
   Sub Copydata()
   Dim myWB As Workbook
   Dim thisWB As Workbook
   Dim thisWS As Worksheet

   Set myWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\test.xlsx")

   myWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C12").Select
   Selection.Copy

   Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
   Set thisWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test data")

   thisWB.Activate   
   thisWS.Select

  Selection.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,  Operation:=xlNone,SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   myWB.Close

   End Sub
```

Comment: Your code will work fine if you make this change ~thisWB.Activate
   thisWS.Range("A1").Select
With Selection
 .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
   
   End With~ Though I do not recommend select method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` statements are dangerous and slow down your code a lot. Try using this

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copydata()
    Dim myWB As Workbook
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet

    Set myWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\test.xlsx")

    myWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C12").Copy

    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set thisWS = thisWB.Sheets("Test data")

    thisWB.Activate
    thisWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    myWB.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly1 Faster too !

Comment: You could make it faster still my setting screenupdating to false at the beginning too